# Managing Azure subs when MSFT and Organizational use same email

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, azure-management

Scenario: Years ago I created a Azure subscription using my Microsoft account that has a user ID of my primary email (primary@foo.com). Then Office 365 came along and I created an account and moved my email there so I now had an Organizational Account with a user ID of the same primary email (primary@foo.com). So at this point I now have two different types of accounts that both use the same user ID.

The problem: setting the OrgAccount as a co-admin of my Azure subscription doesn't appear possible.

I went into my Azure account and added my Office 365 directory to my Azure subscriptions... it worked and I can see my users. But when I try to add the OrgAccount as a co-admin so I can manage my Azure subscription from Office 365, Azure only finds the MSFT account (you add it by adding the email of the account).

So is it not possible to do what I'm trying to do? Will I need to create a dummy admin user in Office 365? This kills the idea of having a single login though...

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted... this wasn't very clear because the names of my directories were so similar.

tldr
The problem was that each subscription is tied to a directory. My subscription was still tied to the same initial directory created when I had my Microsoft Account (aka: MSA) so whenever I tried to add a new admin, it only looked up the user in the old directory.

The fix:
Go change the directory associated with a subscription. This is in the Subscriptions > Manage Subscriptions/Directory menu in the top header. After I did that, when I tried to add the user that had the same user ID as my MSA and OrgId, I got an option to pick OrgID or MSA to add as the admin.